# Combining two different JavaScript functions to get JSON sibling data

Tags: javascript

I have two function.
One- that on 'Click' gets the id value.
second- gets the sibling data from an id.

I want to combine the two functions, so when i click a div, get that 'id' and display the sibling data from JSON

```
//this returns sibling data from JSON with id=2
const result = characters.find(item => {
  // if this returns `true` then the currently 
  // iterated item is the one found
  return item.id === 2 
});

console.log(result);

//this allows me to click the different divs to get their id
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".characterBox");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
  });
}
```

Comment: So do a `characters.find(item => { return item.id === this.getAttribute("id") });` inside your click handler …? (Of course you should rather store `this.getAttribute("id")` into a variable first, and use that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the logic directly into the anonymous function and use `this.getAttribute("id")` instead `2`

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".characterBox");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const result = characters.find(item => {
      return item.id == this.getAttribute("id")
    });
    console.log(result);
  });   
}
```

Comment: the result in console.log becomes <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul> repeated the same amount as the character list... what am I missing! I feel like we are close...

Comment: thats before clicking the div, clicking the div did nothing.

Comment: I updated the code, the console log is at the correct place